# Is it safe/bad practice to upate SuperVisor strategy from supervisor in Akka?

Tags: java, scala, akka

In the below actor hierarchy there is a parent supervisor which creates a child supervisor. To configure the number of retries in the SupervisorStrategy
of the child supervisor I send the value from the parent to the child and update the supervisor strategy accordingly.

Pseudecode:

```
public class ParentSupervisor {

    parent = myActorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(ChildSupervisor.class);

    parent.tell(3);
}

public class ChildSupervisor {

    int numRetries;

    @Override
    public SupervisorStrategy supervisorStrategy() {
        //use numRetries in strategy 
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if (message instanceof Integer) {
            this.numRetries = (Integer) message
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a safe implemenation? Since I'm exposing `numRetries` perhaps I should not do this. Are there other mechanisms to update the Supervisor parameters at runtime?

Update :

Reading http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/fault-tolerance.html it states "strategy cannot be changed afterwards as it is an integral part of the actor system’s structure." but this is acceptable as each strategy is associated to just that actor instance so as new actors are created the strategy will be updated.

If the supervisor strategy can be invoked before the onReceive method then this means "numEntries" (referring to pseudocode example in this question) could be set to 0 instead of 3. This implies if I use `new OneForOneStrategy(numRetries` then the max number of retries is set to 0. This is undesirable behavior as I want the parent supervisor to set the max number of retries within the child supervisor, but if numRetries could potentially be 0 then this is unusable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the parts of the implementation that you show are indeed safe. The supervisor strategy is invoked just like onReceive in the course of processing a message (namely the failure of the child actor) and therefore you can access the actor’s state from within its implementation, including reads and writes.

Update (in response to question update):

The supervisor strategy can only be invoked after the actor has created child actors. Since the actor is free to not create child actors until it has received the needed numRetries message, it can ensure that everything is properly set up before the first failure can occur.

It should be noted that the `supervisorStrategy` method is used every time when a child signals a failure, which means that it is usually beneficial to cache the strategy in an instance variable. Upon reception of a new `numRetries` value the strategy could be replaced with a new one that is in effect from then on.

Comment: thanks, so method supervisorStrategy is always called after onReceive method for an actor?

Comment: No, an actor’s onReceive method is called whenever it receives a message, and an actor’s supervisorStrategy is invoked whenever a child of that actor threw an exception. These are independent actions, so the two can be called in any order, but Akka ensures that only of of them is called at a time (i.e. they do not interrupt each other).

Comment: "an actor’s supervisorStrategy is invoked whenever a child of that actor threw an exception. these are independent actions, so the two can be called in any order," Does this not imply that numRetries in above pseudocode may not be set as supervisorStrategy could potentially be called before onReceive ?

Comment: yes, of course, it will be zero until the first Integer message

Comment: thanks for your comments, but I feel I'm not understanding something fundamental, can you see my question update ? I do not think I can use this solution to configure supervisorStrategy parameters at runtime for reason specified in update.